# What does this Youtube API Response Mean?

Tags: python, json, youtube-api, httpresponse

I am making some requests to the Youtube API using Python. I am inputting a list of video ids, retrieving the data, and parsing the response into json objects. Some of those objects are as expected like:

```
"title": "Review | American Duchess and Simplicity 8579 Panniers (Pocket hoops) Pattern"
```

And then some are of a long list like:

```
"title": "\u3010\u558b\u308b\u732b\u3011\u5bdd\u307c\u3051\u3066\u8a00\u8449\u3092\u9593
\u9055\u3048\u305f\u3051\u3069\u3001\u8a00\u3044\u76f4\u3057\u305f\u3046\u3061\u306e\u732b\u304c
\u6551\u3044\u3088\u3046\u304c\u306a\u3044\u2026\u53ef\u611b\u3055\u3067\u3010\u30e1\u30ed\u308b
\u3011"
```

Clearly it's not nonsense, but I have no idea what these mean and if it is meaningful at all. I am hoping to do data analysis on video's metadata. Does anyone know?

Comment: That's a title in Chinese.  You can Google U+558B and U+732B etc.

Answer (score 1):

Doing some more digging it is unicode (which I know now more about) and this was occurring because of json + emoji decoding.

This fixed it:

```
json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)
```